# What is the evaluation step in an HE scheme?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I quote:

> By homomorphic encryption, we mean the family of encryption schemes
> being able to perform homomorphic operations on ciphertexts, without
> decrypting them. The first time someone introduced such a notion goes
> back to 1978, when Rivest, Adleman and Dertouzos [RAD78] described the
> privacy homomorphisms. An homomorphic encryption scheme, as
> traditional encryption schemes, has a key generation, an encryption
> and a decryption algorithm, and it has an additional algorithm called
> evaluation.

- Key generation
- Encryption
- Decryption
- Evaluation

How could one explain to someone with zero background on cryptography, what the evaluation step entails ?

Comment: Do you want to know _what_ it does in an abstract sense or (also?) how it does that in some arbitrary selection of schemes?

Comment: Yes a simplification would be great

Comment: Yes thank you !